# Generating mulitple types from other types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Say I have some types:

```js
type A = ...;
type B = ...;
type C = ...;
type MyTypes = A | B | C;
```

And then I have a generic type transformer:

```js
type Transformed<T extends MyTypes> = ...;
```

Then I would like to automatically export all transformed types, i.e. autogenerate:

```
type ATrans = Transformed<A>;
type BTrans = Transformed<B>;
type CTrans = Transformed<C>;
```

Without having to type that every time I add a new type to MyTypes.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type A = { tag: 'a' };
type B = { tag: 'B' };
type C = { tag: 'C' };

type MyTypes = A | B | C;

type Transformation<T> = { transformed: T }

type Transformed<T extends MyTypes> = T extends any ? Transformation<T> : never

// Transformation<A> | Transformation<B> | Transformation<C>
type Result = Transformed<MyTypes>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVgEMDmAuKByNuUAvgNwBQokUAQgsqpjrtYaReNAMJ0rrZ6dW5dlQCyIACocAznTgAfGlEWdhlaBIBOaAHbSAZgHtNAWzTAAloZ0AeCQD4eqbXqOmIAExwTiZERpcDYxNPOygIAA9gCB0PWXEpSGlHRB9I6NjZXRAoAH4oLV0g03MrWwcoHB0IADcITT8AekaCwLczS2sbGEdFQtdg0q7qXtai9qHbTnt-KAAlCGkAVwAbYDp%204pCPGwSZGaA)

After this line `T extends any` union gets distributed

Comment: Thanks! But I was literally hoping to `export type ATrans = Transform<A>`, but automatically.

Comment: @ThorCorreia you also can create a tuple with three elements, but there is no way to automatically change source code an add  `export type ATrans = Transform<A>` to the end of the file. For this purpose, you need to write TS compiler plugin. There is no `macros`

Comment: Thank! Yeah, coming from Rust, I tend to think in macros and this would be an excellent one.

Comment: Rust macroses are complete magic for me ;)